# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#create, Couldn't find Post with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After clicking on create comment, i got error like this

[image]

coment controller:

`
I used FriendlyId instead of post id.

error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#create
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=

class CommentsController < ApplicationController

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end


    comments form: _comments.html.erb

    `<%= form_for([@post,@post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
       <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
       </p>
       <p>
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
       </p>
       <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
       </p>
    <% end %>`

posts controller:  post_controller.rb

    `class PostsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def index
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
      end

      def show
      end

      def new
        @post = Post.new
      end

      def edit
      end

      def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @post.save
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @post.update(post_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @post.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        def set_post
          @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
        end

        def post_params
          params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :image)
        end
    end
    `
    model: post.rb

    class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "900x380#", thumb: "300x165>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

Comment: You are passing `second-post-about-laptop` in params[:post_id] instead of id

Comment: Error is that `post is not finding using id "second-post-about-laptop"` in line `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`

Comment: Can you show your view/form that is submitting data to this create method?

Comment: _form.html.erb:`<%= form_for([@post,@post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
   <p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </p>
   <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
   </p>
   <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
   </p>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
@post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
```

After you add this, add a new column to your database table by running

```
rails g migration AddSlugToPosts slug:uniq
```

After you have done this, locate your post model and add:

```
extend FriendlyId 
friendly_id :first_name, use: :slugged
```

Note: I use `first_name` for my slug. It's up to you which one you want to use, you can read more about how to setup friendly [here](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).